# How can we get members information in a Microsoft teams group through logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get chat members information from a teams group through logic app. So is there a connector through which we can do that?

Comment: Please add what have you tried and where you are facing the errors

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [Logic App teams connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/) to get te details who has posted the message. But in case if you need more information for that user than you need to leverage the [Azure AD connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/) ([Get User Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/#get-user)) to get the user information.